# Hibernate, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

Tags: hibernate

I have a problem, when I set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create but table doesn't created

```
@Bean
public Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", hibernateShowSql);
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernateHBM2DDLAuto);
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", hibernateFormatSql);

    return properties;
}
@Bean
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    return new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource())
            .scanPackages("model")
            .addProperties(hibernateProperties())
            .buildSessionFactory();
}
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: what is the value of `hibernateHBM2DDLAuto`? Can you print it and check? And which version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: value of hibernateHBM2DDLAuto - create, hibernate version 4.2.0